# Trying to install locally "Prestashop" but INTL isn't installed correctly

Tags: php, prestashop, intl

I'm trying to install Prestashop locally on my WAMP server without any success, when I execute the command `php composer.phar install` the terminal gives me this error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.

I've checked already phpinfo(), and it loads php.ini from the following path:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf
>   Loaded Configuration File   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini

In php.ini I've already enabled INTL extension as the following:
extension=intl.so

But doesn't seems to work.. any suggestions?

Comment: Did you restart your services after enabling it?

Comment: Not sure about MAMP, but usually there are two `php.ini` files on your system, one for your webserver implementation, the other for PHP CLI. Since `composer` is run via CLI I guess you got the wrong one.

Comment: @WKoppel : Yes already done.

Comment: @kerbholz Oh great thanks I've enabled intl extention on PHP CLI but now when I run the command php composer.phar install, it gives me this error: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't install with composer, try to download the file [Here](https://download.prestashop.com/download/releases/prestashop_1.7.4.3.zip),

Dezip the two files,

Now you have Index.php and prestashop.zip,

Place them on MAMP/www/yourPrestashopFolder,

And now go on your web browser on : localhost/yourPrestashopFolder,

Follow the steps , and your Prestashop site is ready to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Composer is running with the php of the system, not with the php of your wamp server, you need change the "path" variable of the system to run with the php of your wamp, here a tutorial about how to change the path: https://john-dugan.com/add-php-windows-path-variable/